# How to handle data migration integrity issues?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, data-migration, scriptella

I am dealing with a data migration from an old SQL Server 8 database to an Oracle 11g. I am talking about 100 tables more or less and tons of data. I am using Scriptella ETL. The problem is, there have been changes in foreign keys, there are new constraints for the new database, so there are integrity errors when enabling constraints after executing the migration. I have executed it in two different development environments and the errors are different, so I had to solve it manually. With such amount of data is impossible to predict where those errors are going to appear in testing and production environment. What is the best way to handle this issue?

Thanks!

Edited 10/28/2016:

I found Oracle has this option "ENABLE NOVALIDATE" so I tried it and it works! But now my question is, there is negative consequences to have data without integrity in DB?

Comment: The best way is to make a very conservative estimate about how long it will take, tell your boss and let someone else make a decision on integrity vs cost.

Comment: But I need to deliver a script that handles it, because the execution in production environment is going to be performed by customer, not me

Comment: That's fine, but people need to understand it's going to take a long time. The real problem is: if there is an integrity error, it takes a human to sort it out - you can't use an automatic script to decide whether this thing is meant to be an apple or an orange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by using the Oracle option "ENABLE NOVALIDATE" though I don't know if it has negative side effects.